# How to evaluate the performance of Machine Learning classifiers using Python by using Paired t-test?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, hypothesis-test, statistical-test

I am quite beginner in machine learning. I am trying to conduct a t-test for the difference of means to assess which algorithm achieves higher F1 score. I have results of both algorithms Such as F1_score for algorithm A is 0.63 and other 0.89 for algorithm B.

I have applied the following code but I am unable to sort it out and did not understand the error very well.
How can I compare two algorithms? and get the performance results from hypothesis testing?

```
X = data_frame.iloc[:, 3:]
y = data_frame.iloc[:,2:-7]

from mlxtend.evaluate import paired_ttest_5x2cv

t, p = paired_ttest_5x2cv(estimator1=f1_score_Algo_A, estimator2=f1_score_Algo_B, X=X, y=y)
alpha = 0.05

print('t statistic: %.3f' % t)
print('aplha ', alpha)
print('p value: %.3f' % p)

if p > alpha:
  print("Fail to reject null hypotesis")
else:
  print("Reject null hypotesis")
```

```
from mlxtend.evaluate import paired_ttest_5x2cv
----> t, p = paired_ttest_5x2cv(estimator1=lr_f1,estimator2=dt_f1, X=X, y=y, random_seed=1)
alpha = 0.05
print('t statistic: %.3f' % t)
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute '_estimator_type'
```

Expected outcome will be which algorithm has performed well on the basis of F1_Score.

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages; see how to create a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The function `paired_ttest_5x2cv()` expects the trained models (to be compared) as inputs, not the `F1 scores`.

Here is the reproduced error with `iris` dataset (try with your dataset) and couple of models (a LR and a DT model, try with your own models):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from mlxtend.data import iris_data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

X, y = iris_data()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25,
                     random_state=123)
algo_A = LogisticRegression(random_state=1, max_iter=1000)
algo_B = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1, max_depth=1)

y_pred = algo_A.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
f1_score_Algo_A = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')

y_pred = algo_B.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
f1_score_Algo_B = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')

print(f'Algo A score: {f1_score_Algo_A}, Algo B score: {f1_score_Algo_B}')

from mlxtend.evaluate import paired_ttest_5x2cv

t, p = paired_ttest_5x2cv(estimator1=f1_score_Algo_A, estimator2=f1_score_Algo_B, X=X, y=y)
#t, p = paired_ttest_5x2cv(estimator1=algo_A, estimator2=algo_B, X=X, y=y)
alpha = 0.05

print('t statistic: %.3f' % t)
print('aplha ', alpha)
print('p value: %.3f' % p)

if p > alpha:
  print("Fail to reject null hypotesis")
else:
  print("Reject null hypotesis")

# if estimator1._estimator_type == "classifier":
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute '_estimator_type'
```

Now, try with the trained models instead, it will work:

```
print(f'Algo A score: {f1_score_Algo_A}, Algo B score: {f1_score_Algo_B}')

from mlxtend.evaluate import paired_ttest_5x2cv

t, p = paired_ttest_5x2cv(estimator1=algo_A, estimator2=algo_B, X=X, y=y)
alpha = 0.05

print('t statistic: %.3f' % t)
print('aplha ', alpha)
print('p value: %.3f' % p)

if p > alpha:
  print("Fail to reject null hypotesis")
else:
  print("Reject null hypotesis")

# Algo A score: 0.9736842105263158, Algo B score: 0.631578947368421
# t statistic: 8.000
# aplha  0.05
# p value: 0.000       
# Reject null hypotesis
```

Note that the `F1 scores` computed above are not used while the paired `t-tests` are executed (here the scores are computed on the held-out test dataset just to have an idea about the models' performances), the actual scores on the `CV`
splits are computed with the scoring function while the `t-tests` are done.

Comment: it's working now but the my confusion is still there, how I can compare the performance of two classifiers to check whether which one classifier has performed well? Such as I want to conduct a t-test for the difference of means to assess which algorithm achieves higher F1 score.

Comment: As per documentation, the function uses 2-fold cross validation, computes the performance of the candidate models on the train-test splits twice for 5 iterations and uses combined paored t-test to compute whether one classifier significantly outperformed the other one, with a certain level of significance. The function also accepts a `scoring` argument that you can provide to use your metric to performance evaluation instead of the default one (accuracy).